# Am able to store the image in my computer drive. but unable to display on page

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3 with Hibernate. And I'm stuck with displaying the image. I am perfectly able to upload the image but I am unable to display it after the successful upload. Please suggest me where I had stepped wrong .below is the code i am trying.

This is my controller:

```
  private String uploadFolderPath;
  ServletConfig config;

  public String getUploadFolderPath() {
  return uploadFolderPath;
  }

public void setUploadFolderPath(String uploadFolderPath) {
this.uploadFolderPath = uploadFolderPath;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfile",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getUploadForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(new UploadItem());
    return "/uploadfile";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfile",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String create(UploadItem uploadItem, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors,
    HttpSession session) {
  try {

    MultipartFile filea = uploadItem.getFileData();

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    if (filea.getSize() > 0) {
        inputStream = filea.getInputStream();
        // File realUpload = new File("C:/");

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\images\\"
                + filea.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("====22=========");
        System.out.println(filea.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("=============");
        int readBytes = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("===ddd=======");
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        session.setAttribute("uploadFile", "C:\\images\\"
                + filea.getOriginalFilename());
      }
     } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "uploadfileindex";
   }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfileindex",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showRegistration(Model model) {
  return "uploadfileindex";
  }

  // Process the form.
  @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfileindex",method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String processRegistration(BindingResult result) {
  return "uploadfileindex";
```

**uploadfile jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

  <html>
  <head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Upload Example</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  function Validate()
  {
 var image =document.getElementById("image").value;
 if(image!=''){
  var checkimg = image.toLowerCase();
   if (!checkimg.match(/(\.jpg|\.png|\.JPG|\.PNG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/)){
  alert("Please enter Image File Extensions .jpg,.png,.jpeg");
  document.getElementById("image").focus();
  return false;
   }
   }
   return true;
 } 
  </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <form:form modelAttribute="uploadItem" name="frm" method="post"
   enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return Validate();">
   <fieldset><legend>Upload File</legend>
   <table>
   <tr>
  <td><form:label for="fileData" path="fileData">File</form:label><br />
   </td>
  <td><form:input path="fileData" id="image" type="file" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><br />
  </td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
  </form:form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**uploadfileindex.jsp**

```
   <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
   <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ page session="true"%>
   <%@taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <html>
   <head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2><a href="uploadfile.jsp">Upload Example</a></h2>
  <%
   if (session.getAttribute("uploadFile") != null
   && !(session.getAttribute("uploadFile")).equals("")) {
  %>
  <h3>Uploaded File</h3>
  <br>
  <img src="<%=session.getAttribute("uploadFile")%>" alt="Upload Image" />

  <%
  session.removeAttribute("uploadFile");
   }
   %>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you have that image on your hard drive but you are not able to display it over the web page. So what you need to do is, place your image in the installation directory that is from where the MVC is installed. Like is we use an WAMP server, we store image in `wamp\www\yourprojectfolder\image.jpg`. Like this you'll be fetching your image directly through the web page.

Comment: <img src="C:\images\10551946_510222132457284_1002868246_n.jpg" alt="Upload Image"> in console am getting this. when i copy this source and enter in url image is displayed. but i want in the page after successful pload

Comment: hey you are getting me wrong, place your image in the final installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/imageServer")
public class ImageServer {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{imageUrl:.+}")
    public void getImageByUrl(@PathVariable String imageUrl, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
    {

        String filesFolder = "C:/images";
        File finalImage = new File(filesFolder+"/"+imageUrl);
        FileInputStream fileStream=new FileInputStream(finalImage);      

                try {
                    response.getOutputStream().write(IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream));
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                    response.getOutputStream().close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
```

And on your JSP Page, go for :

```
<img src"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imageServer/image.jpg">
```

So you can see `C:/images/image.jpg` in your webo page.

Comment: thanks...i'll try..if any issue i'll let u know.. and this controller you given should i add this or replace with my controller?

Comment: Yes, Add this controller, and call it from your jsp, with your image name of the filesystem as show in the example.

Comment: can tell me the errors you're getting in your browser ?

Comment: in browser cosole <img src="/CustomerPortal/ImageServer/10551946_510222132457284_1002868246_n.jpg"> when i mouse hover on it a message is popping as failed to load given url

Comment: change *ImageServer* to *imageServer* in your JSP

Comment: <img src="/CustomerPortal/imageServer/10551946_510222132457284_1002868246_n.jpg"> same issue even i changed ti imageServer

Comment: Have you checked that you have 10551946_510222132457284_1002868246_n.jpg under **C:/images** directory ?

Comment: yeah. when i upload any image it is storing in the C:/images directory. i called with the same image name in jsp. but still it is not displaying image

Comment: i followed this example http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring3/mvc/Spring3MVCImageUpload.html and added the controller which you given mate.

Comment: am storing in C:/images. but in jsp it is taking <img src="/CustomerPortal/imageServer/Capture.jpg">

Comment: didn't you have a *no mapping found error* in your eclipse console ?